# Calling Google AdWords API from Apex

Tags: integration, callout

I have contacted Google API for request to pull the data from adwords account .

They suggested use below format of PHP code to call from Rest API.

```
#!/bin/bash
ENDPOINT='https://googleads.googleapis.com'
VERSION='v3'                                                                    
CID=6602583583                                                                  

QUERY='
  SELECT
    campaign.advertising_channel_type,
    metrics.all_conversions,
    metrics.cost_per_conversion,
    metrics.impressions,
    metrics.interactions
  FROM campaign                                                                   
'

curl -v --header "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" --header "developer-token: $DEV_TOKEN" --data query="$QUERY" $PROD_ENDPOINT/$VERSION/customers/$CID/googleAds:search.
```

I tried below format of Rest resource to call the google adwords API .I am not sure whether i am sending right request same as above like PHP.

When I run below code I am getting error "status not found".

```
Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse httpRes = new HttpResponse();
    String Query='SELECT campaign.advertising_channel_type, metrics.all_conversions, metrics.cost_per_conversion,metrics.impressions,  metrics.interactions FROM campaign';
    httpReq.setEndpoint('https://googleads.googleapis.com/v3/customers/6602583583/googleAds:search');
    httpReq.setMethod('POST');
    httpReq.setHeader('developer-token', 'developertoken');
    httpReq.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer+Access token');
    httpReq.setHeader('login-customer-id', 'customerid');
    httpReq.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    httpReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    httpReq.setHeader('Host', 'googleads.googleapis.com');
    httpReq.setHeader('Content-Length', '784');
    httpReq.setBody('Query');
    httpRes = (new Http()).send(httpReq);
        if(httpRes.getStatusCode() == 200){
            string response1= httpRes.getBody();
            System.debug('#### HtteRes '+HttpRes.getBody());
            Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response1);
         system.debug('response map values to verify'+ responseMap);   
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse httpRes = new HttpResponse();
String Query='SELECT campaign.advertising_channel_type,campaign.resource_name, metrics.all_conversions, metrics.cost_per_conversion,metrics.impressions,metrics.interaction_rate ,metrics.interactions,metrics.conversions_from_interactions_rate,metrics.cost_per_all_conversions FROM campaign';
httpReq.setEndpoint('https://googleads.googleapis.com/v3/customers/customerid/googleAds:search');
httpReq.setMethod('POST');
httpReq.setHeader('developer-token', 'developer token');
httpReq.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer + Access token');
httpReq.setHeader('login-customer-id', 'customerid');
httpReq.setBody('query='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(Query, 'UTF-8'));
httpRes = (new Http()).send(httpReq);
    if(httpRes.getStatusCode() == 200){
        string response1= httpRes.getBody();
        System.debug('#### HtteRes '+HttpRes.getBody());
        Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response1);
     system.debug('response map values to verify'+ responseMap);   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From curl [docs](https://ec.haxx.se/http/http-post):

> When the data is sent by a browser after data have been filled in a
>   form, it will send it "URL encoded", as a serialized `name=value` pairs
>   separated with ampersand symbols (`&`). You send such data with curl's
>   `-d` or `--data` option

The equivalent in Apex is

```java
req.setBody('query='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(Query, 'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: Hi Identigral,

Thank you fro your answer.I changed the code tried again but still getting same error.

Comment: The only remaining difference between PHP/Curl example and your Apex headers are extra headers `Host`, `Content-Length` and `login-customer-id`. You can try removing them and see if it makes a difference. This is likely not a Salesforce-side issue. [Google Ads (REST) API](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start) is in beta status and the doc pages aren't even responding right now. If it still doesn't work, recommend you switch to the officially supported [Google AdWords (SOAP) API](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/start).

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion .We just need to remove HOSt and Content Length .the login-customer-id.  required to fetch the data.